# Non-affecting the main the property of interest

Tags: single-word-requests

Suppose that we analyse the speed of a car. Then important (lower level) properties of a car to consider are: an engine, aerodynamics, weight, etc. But there are also other properties of a car that are important for some other use, but do not affect the speed of a car in a direct way, e.g. the availability of airbags concerns the safety (rather than the speed) of a car.

Note, here the properties of the speed and safety are at the same level of an abstraction of a car. The properties lower from them, an engine and an availability of an airbag are at the same level of an abstraction of a car too.

I would like an English word (a noun or an adjective) for a property that:

1. does not affect the main property P1 of interest,
2. has a clear purpose and affects some other property P2 where the properties P1 and P2 as attributes concern the same level of detail.

Comment: Such a property would be _irrelevant to P1_. If you want to indicate the property is not irrelevant overall you can mention that is _relevant_ to P2.

Comment: I don't follow the question. Does 1 say that "P1 does not affect P1"?

Comment: A kind of sister-property, an independent entity ranking *pari-passu* with the first and sharing its status as a factor. There's likely to be a good word for that, let's try.

Comment: How about _coordinate_ or _coordinating_ ?

Comment: @Rupe A typo corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you may refer to non essential properties as *[accessories](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/auto+accessory)* (airbags or car radio for instance) or *minor features.*

Comment: In the context of the example I gave it may work, however, I need to a more general and abstract word applicable for my thesis whose example is out of the scope to explain.